# How do I find out why Eclipse is stuck in an endless build cycle?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I've got Eclipse building a Maven project that I just imported. I have Build Automatically checked and Eclipse is constantly building. It builds and waits a few seconds and builds again without me making any changes. I noticed that this only happens when the server is running so I'll include some info on the setup here:

- Have a local install of Tomcat.
- Eclipse is set up to start Tomcat but points the Tomcat executables to a directory of its own making (Server Location is set to "Use workspace metadata").
- Eclipse is set to "Automatically publish when resources change".

As far as I know, Eclipse (or Eclipse's embedded Maven) is building everything into the target directory at the root of my project. Is it possible that Eclipse doesn't realize that the target directory is not supposed to be scanned for changes?

There are zero references checked under the project properties -> Project References.

I'm at a loss as to what this might be. If there are other settings that someone would like me to confirm, please let me know.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552082/eclipse-always-building-workspace) seems to be the same problem but none of the answers seem to apply to me. I'm not sure what the original poster's comment that "added annotation processing to my project which interfere the build process" means.

Answer (score 2):

Does your code generate something in src/main/java or src/main/resources ?
Only then, eclipse scanner can interpret this as 'source change' and then build and deploy continuously.

Any change in 'src' should trigger build
Any change in 'target' should trigger deploy. 
If your code is generating data in target (logging for e.g) you would see tomcat deploy happening continuously